# Are null matrices of different dimensions equal?

Tags: math

For example: I have a null matrix with 2*2 dimensionality and a null matrix with 2 * 3 dimensionality. Are they equal? If not why?

Comment: This question belongs to math.stackexchange.com - every single question here should be directly related to development

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixEquality.html

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you define equality.

Usually, equality would be defined as:

1. has the same dimensionalities
2. has the same value in each cell.

By this definition, they are not equal.

However, you may define matrixes as having infinite dimensions, and just having null values everywhere unless set otherwise. Then they would suddenly be equal.